# Print list of values from HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two classes `Dog.java` and `DogSerach.java` and I want to print dog detail using HashMap. I studied duplicate of this question [get string value from HashMap depending on key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789679/get-string-value-from-hashmap-depending-on-key-name) and also studied Oracle doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html, but still can not figure it out.

I have tried in DogSearch.java

```
for (String key: dogs.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Registration number : " + key);
           System.out.println("Detail : " +  dogs.get(key));
           }
```

But I get

```
Registration number : 1003
Detail : Dog [name=Luca, breed=Labrador, registrationNumber=1003]
Registration number : 1002
Detail : Dog [name=Gracie, breed=Rottweiler, registrationNumber=1002]
Registration number : 1001
Detail : Dog [name=Max, breed=German Shepherd, registrationNumber=1001]
```

I want to print like this

```
Registration number: 1001
Name: Max
Breed: German Shepherd
... etc.
```

**DogSearch.java**

```
public class DogSearch {

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Dog> dogs = new HashMap<String, Dog>();

        Dog max = new Dog("Max", "German Shepherd", "1001");
        Dog gracie = new Dog("Gracie", "Rottweiler", "1002");
        Dog luca = new Dog("Luca", "Labrador", "1003");


        dogs.put(max.getRegistrationNumber(), max);
        dogs.put(gracie.getRegistrationNumber(), gracie);
        dogs.put(luca.getRegistrationNumber(), luca);


        System.out.println("List of dogs by name: ");

        for (String key: dogs.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Registration number : " + key);
            System.out.println("Breed : " +  dogs.get(key));

        }

    }
}
```

**Dog.java**

```
class Dog {
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private String registrationNumber;

    public Dog(String name, String breed, String registrationNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public void setBreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public String getRegistrationNumber() {
        return registrationNumber;
    }

    public void setRegistrationNumber(String registrationNumber) {
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((breed == null) ? 0 : breed.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((registrationNumber == null) ? 0 : registrationNumber.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Dog other = (Dog) obj;
        if (breed == null) {
            if (other.breed != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!breed.equals(other.breed))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (registrationNumber == null) {
            if (other.registrationNumber != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!registrationNumber.equals(other.registrationNumber))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dog [name=" + name + ", breed=" + breed + ", registrationNumber=" + registrationNumber + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: nothing to searching, but printing

Comment: I received output as `[name=Gracie, breed=Rottweiler, registrationNumber=1002]` but I want to get with separate one like Name is:  Gracie, Breed is Rottweiler and registrationNumber is 1002.

Comment: Hint: never put more information into comments. Always update your question instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
for (String key: dogs.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("Registration number : " + key);
        System.out.println("Name: " +  dogs.get(key).getName());
        System.out.println("Breed: " +  dogs.get(key).getBreed());
       }
   }
```

With Java 8 streams you can sort the map by the names of your dogs.

```
Map<String, Dog> result = dogs.entrySet().stream() 
      .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(new MyComparator())) 
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, 
           (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

and then loop through the result map.

```
for (String key: result.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Registration number : " + key);
     System.out.println("Name: " +  dogs.get(key).getName());
     System.out.println("Breed: " +  dogs.get(key).getBreed());
   }
```

}

And you need a Comparator class

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Dog>{ 

     public int compare(Dog s1, Dog s2) { 
          return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName()); 
     } 
 }
```

Comment: Is there any way I can print the list of dogs by name. I mean printing list sorted by name?

Comment: There are many ways, but you can check this link http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Collection_How_to/Map/Sort_objects_in_HashMap_on_their_properties_rather_than_values.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want:

The first one is to change the `toString()` method of your `Dog.java`. When using `System.out.println()`, java uses the `toString()` method when passing classes as arguments.
So changing your `toString()` to :

```
return "Name: " + name + "\n" + 
       "Breed: " + breed;
```

should do the trick.

The second way is to change what you print in your for loop.
an example of what you can do is:

```
for (String key: dogs.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Registration number : " + key);
    Dog dog = dogs.get(key);
    System.out.println("Name : " +  dog.getName());
    System.out.println("Breed: " +  dog.getBreed());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you create a method in class **Dog** and write the implementation the way would like to print!

So here you just need

```
for (String key: dogs.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(dogs.get(key).getPrintString());

}
```

This will go in **Dog** class

```
public String getPrintString() { 
 return "Registration number : "+ getRegistrationNumber() +"\nName: " +getName() +"\nBreed:"+getBreed(); // This can be optimized further using StringBuffer
}
```

Comment: Like in` @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dog ` which I just **copied** from his code?

Comment: toString() in general is not for printing in applications, but for short displaying, debug info etc. Sometimes is used, but only in simplest cases

Comment: I guess, in above scenario, it fits the puprose!

Comment: And when application code wants to change order, add wihitespace etc? Agree this is used, but not recomended

Comment: I guess, user is not using toString method anywhere else, so I still recommend to use it rather than printing whole lots of sysout messages.

Comment: You suggest to override toString(). He is already doing that!

Comment: Then, user can define a new method  of printing in class Dog and invoke it. Just updated the solution