# Java : for in for, same arraylist and comparison

Tags: java, object, arraylist, merge, concatenation

I'm facing a small issue. I want to concat two or more object attributes if they have attributes in common.
`fusionAgenda` is my arrayList where I want to compare objects and then concat.
`appointments` is my final arrayList, where I want to add the result of the concatenation.

```
for(PSTAppointment fusion : fusionAgenda){
  System.out.println("------------------");
  System.out.println(fusion.getSubject() + " / " + fusion.getDisplayTo() );
  for(PSTAppointment fusion2 : fusionAgenda){
    if(fusion.getSubject().equals(fusion2.getSubject()) &&
       fusion.getStartTime().equals(fusion2.getStartTime()) &&
       fusion.getLocation().equals(fusion2.getLocation()) &&
       !fusion.getDisplayTo().contains(fusion2.getDisplayTo()) ) {

      fusion.setlisteFusion(fusion.getDisplayTo() + "; "+ fusion2.getDisplayTo());
    }
  }
  System.out.println(fusion.getListeFusion());
  appointements.add(fusion);
}
```

**Here's my `fusionAgenda` data:**

> - Evenement 1 / Personne 1
> - Evenement 1  / Personne 2; Personne3
> - Evenement 2   / Personne 4
> - Evenement 2  / Personne 5
> - Evenement 2  / Personne 6
> - Evenement 2  / Personne 7

**Expected result:**

> - Evenement 1 / Personne 1; Personne 2; Personne 3
> - Evenement 2   / Personne 4; Personne 5; Personne 6; Personne 7

**Actual result:**

> - Evenement 1 / Personne 1; Personne 2; Personne 3
> - Evenement 1 / Personne 2; Personne 3; Personne 1
> - Evenement 2 /  Personne 4; Personne 5
> - Evenement 2 /  Personne 6; Personne 5
> - Evenement 2 /  Personne 7; Personne 5
> - Evenement 2 /  Personne 5; Personne 7

Comment: Please share the code for `PSTAppointment `

Comment: https://github.com/rjohnsondev/java-libpst/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/pff/PSTAppointment.java
I've added manually an attribute (listeFusion, so setListeFusion)

Comment: You don't check if that eveniment was already compared. I suggest to check first if that eveniment don't exist in final list.

Comment: What line d I need to change ?

Comment: In first `for`, before the second `for`, add an `if` which check if `"fusion.evenement"` isn't already in final list, and if it is, you go to next fusion. Atleast you want to group all persons by evenement.

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake in my first post. I need to concat two objects or more, your code is working for 2 objects, but I need to concat two or more objects...

Comment: Have you tried how I said and concat only two objects? If yes, how output look?

Comment: Your code is working, but only for two objects of the list

Comment: How is the final output?

Comment: For Evenement 1 : Personne 1,2,3 (ok), for evenement 2 : personne 4,5

Comment: I've added :   if(appointements.contains(fusion)){continue;}

Comment: You have implemented/override method `contains`?

Comment: What do you get if you call `getToAttendees()` on your  `PSTAppointment` objects, doesn’t it contain the information you’re after?

Comment: I'm using getDisplayTo to get people from different appointment, getAllAttendees don't gave me what i'm looking for

Comment: change `if`, which I talked about, with `for` from here : http://tpcg.io/epocsK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PSTAppointment create method which compares two PSTAppointment objects. This will be easier. For example:

```
    Map<PSTAppointment,PSTAppointment> groupedAppointments = fusionAgenda.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                                             PSTAppointment::getSubject,
                                                             PSTAppointment::getStartTime,
                                                             PSTAppointment::getLocation)
```

Comment: How can I use this after ? (sorry, I'm very new to java...)

Comment: No problem, Map it's a key value list, when You will ask for key using object it will return value assigned to that key

Comment: So this goes into PSTAppointment, but on my main, how do I get this Map ?

Comment: for example that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789679/get-string-value-from-hashmap-depending-on-key-name

Answer (score 0):

This is what i've done to finally make this work :

```
for(PSTAppointment fusion : fusionAgenda){
              System.out.println("------------------");
              System.out.println(fusion.getSubject() + " / " + fusion.getDisplayTo() );
              if(appointements.contains(fusion)) {continue;}
              String attendees = fusion.getDisplayTo()+";";
              for(PSTAppointment fusion2 : copy)
                {
                if(fusion.getSubject().equals(fusion2.getSubject()) && fusion.getStartTime().equals(fusion2.getStartTime()) &&
                   fusion.getLocation().equals(fusion2.getLocation()) && !fusion.getDisplayTo().equals(fusion2.getDisplayTo()) ) {
                     attendees += fusion2.getDisplayTo() +";";
                }
              }
              fusion.setlisteFusion(attendees);
              appointements.add(fusion);
            }
```