# how to extract values from HashMap in java?

Tags: java

Suppose we've a HashMap as follows:

```
{tones=
  [
    {score=0.534486, tone_id=joy, tone_name=Joy},
    {score=0.619262, tone_id=sadness, tone_name=Sadness},
    {score=0.829266, tone_id=analytical, tone_name=Analytical}
  ]
}
```

and we've to extract only "score" values and "tone_name" values from this, how can we do this?

Comment: Please show your attempts thus far

Comment: nice homework. try it couple of hours, if you still cant do it then post here the code you tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get string value from HashMap depending on key name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789679/get-string-value-from-hashmap-depending-on-key-name)

Comment: Or did I get you wrong? What do you mean by _extract values from HashMap_ ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Iterator it = tones.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        if("score".equalsIgnoreCase(pair.getValue()) || "tone_name".equalsIgnoreCase(pair.getValue())){
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```